# How to make a reusable button from a macro?

Tags: vba, excel

Having a working macro, I'd like to reuse it. Namely, to create a button on a toolbar (with a name + icon) that will launch a macro. Tried some tutorials (example: http://www.officetooltips.com/excel/tips/create_a_toolbar_button_or_menu_item_to_run_a_macro.html), but I'd also like to pack the creation code in some file, so that when clicked, the macro would be installed.

Is there an easy way to do it, and if yes, than how? (the best option would work for both Windows and Mac)

Comment: I think creating an Excel add-in (`.xla` or `.xlam` file) would be your best bet here as they'll let you keep all your code in one place and work on both Windows and Mac OS. Chip Pearson has a nice write-up on it at his site: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/createaddin.aspx

Comment: As long as you're OK using the legacy `CommandBars`, then an add-in per @DanWagner's comment is the way to go. Otherwise, you will need to immerse yourself in [customizing the Office fluent ribbon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx) -- not for the faint of heart.

Comment: @DanWagner Thanks (first of all)! So is this the simplest option to create a reusable "button"? No better optione if I'd like to create a ".bat" (or similar) file so when it's clicked - the button will appear in Excel (or on the ribbon)?

Comment: @BreakPhreak an add-in seems like it would be a great fit because each user needs to activate it on his or her machine once, then it's there forever. I'll post an answer below with a couple screenshots to help clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update 4/20: great comment about the complexity of building an add-in. That being said, I'm sure the old timers here would say that something worth doing is worth doing right :). Here is a short walkthrough for creating an add-in:

(1) Save an `xlsm` or `xlsb` file with a name that's easy to increment for versions of your add-in.

(2) Add the following scripts into ThisWorkbook to ensure that you create a menu bar when the workbook is opened and when the workbook is activated:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call CreateMenuBar
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Call CreateMenuBar
End Sub
```

(3) Create a new module and add the following code to create, delete and update your menu bar:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CreateMenuBar()

    Dim MenuObject As CommandBarPopup
    Dim MenuItem As Object
    Dim SubMenuItem As Object

    'clear the old menu bar
    Call DeleteMenuBar("&MyMenuBar")

    'create the menu bar and drop down options
    Set MenuObject = Application.CommandBars(1).Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, _
        before:=10, Temporary:=True)
    MenuObject.Caption = "&MyMenuBar"
    MenuObject.OnAction = "UpdateMenuBar"

    'first level menu option
    Set MenuItem = MenuObject.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup)
    MenuItem.Caption = "&First Menu Stuff"

        'link to first script
        Set SubMenuItem = MenuItem.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
        SubMenuItem.Caption = "&First Script"
        SubMenuItem.OnAction = "Script1"

        'link to second script
        Set SubMenuItem = MenuItem.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
        SubMenuItem.Caption = "&Second Script"
        SubMenuItem.OnAction = "Script2"

    'first level menu option
    Set MenuItem = MenuObject.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup)
    MenuItem.Caption = "&Second Menu Stuff"

        'link to third script
        Set SubMenuItem = MenuItem.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
        SubMenuItem.Caption = "&Third Script"
        SubMenuItem.OnAction = "Script3"

End Sub

Sub DeleteMenuBar(MenuName As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.CommandBars(1).Controls(MenuName).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Sub UpdateMenuBar()
    'do special checks, like verifying sheets, in this routine
End Sub
```

(4) Verify your scripts work and save the file.

(5) Save the file again as an `xlam` or `xla` file and distribute that to users. Boom!

--Original post below--

Here's what an add-in looks like on a Windows Excel instance:

[image: windows]

And here's what an add-in looks like on a Mac Excel instance:

[image]

An add-in can be very handy if you develop many scripts for a fleet of users and want to ensure they're all using the same code.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it after the weekend and will let you know. The thing that bothers me now is that add-in (to be installed) needs to be copied to a certain dir manually. I'd like it to be installed with a click (ideally). Not a dealbreaker though.

Comment: AutoIt might be a good solution for that level of automation. Here's a S.O. post related to installing Excel Add-ins with AutoIt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669201/autoit-load-excell-addin

Comment: Well, I guess it could be the way, but can't answer this question since the development of the add-in was significantly more complicated than declaring a macro button. Approving the answer tentatively.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this on another question, but it wasn't what they were looking for. Would this work for you?

In the options for Excel, click on Customize Ribbon. Above the list of things you can add there should be a dropdown box where you can select Macros. The list should then be populated with macros to add to your ribbon!

[image: Adding a macro to the ribbon]

Comment: Thanks! couldnt find the "customize ribbon" on my Mac Office, I'll try to check at work in a few days