# Using Excel Macros on a XSLX document

Tags: excel, xlsx, vba

This is going to be a long question I'm afraid.

We ask our customers to fill-in in an excel-document with some client-data. This data is separated in columns (Id, Name, Phone, etc). I have a hidden worksheet where these column-headers are mapped to fields which we use in our database. For security reasons I don't want/cannot distribute this file as a macro-enabled document. But when they send the file back I want to execute a macro on this file which saves the content into an CSV so this file can be imported in the DB.

I was thinking of creating the macro in the PERSONAL.XSLB file so I can use it on the returned XSLX file.

It this the correct way to handle it like this? Or should I use a different approach?

Thanks for any help

[Edit]
By the way if there is already an answer for this, I couldn't find it. Maybe I didn't use the correct search terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a great opportunity for an `Add-in` -- I wrote a post about it here: [How to make a reusable button from a macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135211/how-to-make-a-reusable-button-from-a-macro/23141600#23141600)

Here is a short summary of the VBA:

(1) Save an `xlsm` or `xlsb` file with a name that's easy to increment for versions of your add-in.

(2) Add the following scripts into ThisWorkbook to ensure that you create a menu bar when the workbook is opened and when the workbook is activated:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call CreateMenuBar
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Call CreateMenuBar
End Sub
```

(3) Create a new module and add the following code to create, delete and update your menu bar:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CreateMenuBar()

    Dim MenuObject As CommandBarPopup
    Dim MenuItem As Object
    Dim SubMenuItem As Object

    'clear the old menu bar
    Call DeleteMenuBar("&MyMenuBar")

    'create the menu bar and drop down options
    Set MenuObject = Application.CommandBars(1).Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, _
        before:=10, Temporary:=True)
    MenuObject.Caption = "&MyMenuBar"
    MenuObject.OnAction = "UpdateMenuBar"

    'first level menu option
    Set MenuItem = MenuObject.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup)
    MenuItem.Caption = "&First Menu Stuff"

        'link to first script
        Set SubMenuItem = MenuItem.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
        SubMenuItem.Caption = "&First Script"
        SubMenuItem.OnAction = "Script1"

        'link to second script
        Set SubMenuItem = MenuItem.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
        SubMenuItem.Caption = "&Second Script"
        SubMenuItem.OnAction = "Script2"

    'first level menu option
    Set MenuItem = MenuObject.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup)
    MenuItem.Caption = "&Second Menu Stuff"

        'link to third script
        Set SubMenuItem = MenuItem.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
        SubMenuItem.Caption = "&Third Script"
        SubMenuItem.OnAction = "Script3"

End Sub

Sub DeleteMenuBar(MenuName As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.CommandBars(1).Controls(MenuName).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Sub UpdateMenuBar()
    'do special checks, like verifying sheets, in this routine
End Sub
```

(4) Verify your scripts work and save the file.

(5) Save the file again as an `xlam` or `xla` file and you've now got your scripts handy!