# Calling a macro from another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a master excel file that has codes for several macros for example: 
`Sub ExtractDate()`, `Sub RemoveBlankSpaces()` and `Sub ReMoveOlderDates()`.

What I am trying to do is each time I download a new excel spreadsheet from the server, I want to be able to apply those same macros that are in the master excel file to the file being downloaded from the server without having to copy and paste the codes from the master excel file to the new file.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: One good way to solve this problem is to turn your master excel file into an Add-in. Here's a write-up I did on that in a different SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135211/how-to-make-a-reusable-button-from-a-macro

Comment: Hey Dan, thanks for the reply. If you could by any chance clarify, so am I adding the codes that you posted on the other link to my master excel file that has the macros I want to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common way to execute a macro on any Excel file (you can hence add some consistency check rules into your code) is the following:

1) Add the code you want to always execute into the `ThisWorkbook_Open` event of the master sheet. You can access the event from the VBE, by clicking on "This Workbook" on the modules tree and then selecting the open event. This is the idea:

```
Private Sub ThisWorkbook_Open()
    ExtractDate
    RemoveBlankSpaces
    RemoveOlderDates
    'etc.
End Sub
```

Don't forget to add an eventual data validation, if wanted (e.g. If name file is "this" then execute)

2) Save this workbook as "`.xlam`", give it the name and the location you prefer (it will just create a copy, you will not overwrite the original master workbook)

3) Open a new Excel file, then go to File / Options / Add-In, hence Browse (my Excel is in French, the names might be slightly different but this is the logic)

4) Into the browsing window, look for your `.xlam` file and add it to the list of checked add-ins

From now on, everytime you will open an Excel file the macros that are called in the `ThisWorkbook_Open` event of your .xlam file (generated from your master workbook) will be executed.

**Important note**

If in your macro there are references such as "`ThisWorkbook.Range("A1")`", don't forget to replace them in the master file with "`ActiveWorbook`" before to save it as `.xlam`, otherwise you will run the macro on the add-in and not in the currently open workbook. If you don't want to touch your original file, you can always edit this code into the add-in itself accessing it from any Excel instance in the VBE (the tree will always be there if the Add-In is activated).

Comment: @JamesCammer, could you please post a snapshot? This is really, really strange. You might just have an old Excel, do you have ".xla" ?

Comment: It was a stupid question, I figured it out myself. Thanks so much Matteo!! You are the best :)

Comment: @JamesCammer no problem, don't hesitate to add the source of confusion if you think it might help someone else with your same problem in the future!

Comment: Matteo, I just have one more question. If I want to be able to run the macros by going into developer mode and then clicking on macro, is there a way to do that? Like say for example, in the master excel file, can I just add a module and then add "sub ExtractDate()", sub RemoveBlankSpaces()....etc.

Comment: @JamesCammer that would be much tricky, and anyway your document should be ".xlsm" for holding and executing macros at module level. I suggest you to look for the keywords "VBA - how to add a custom button to the ribbon", and if you have troubles open another thread on SO (you can post me the link to your new question here in comments), becuase this is another question with a different approach to solve it.